# How can i turn off the origin axes in gazebo?

Tags: gazebo

i want to turn off the origin (axes) in gazebo. I already turned off the grid with:

```
<scene>
  <grid>false</grid>
</scene>
```

I tried false</origin but it doesn't work.

Thank you so much in advance !

I FOUND A SOLUTION:

```
<scene>
  <grid>false</grid>
  <origin_visual>false</origin_visual>
</scene>
```

Comment: Can you post your solution in an answer and accept it? Then this question will not show up as unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

I FOUND A SOLUTION:

```
<scene>
  <origin_visual>false</origin_visual>
</scene>
```